# Finding matches after a specific line in Perl/Notepad++

Tags: regex, perl, notepad++

My problem is that I have a document that is split into sections, each section is noted by a single line header - [Header1], [Header2], etc. - and contains various types of data sets separated into individual lines, where each line is begun by a label indicating what type of data follows, like this:

```
[Header1]

data_label_type1      = 1,2,3
data_label_type2   = 1,2,3,4
data_label_type1     = 1,2,3,4,5
data_label_type3    = 1,2
```

Note the headers/sections are out of order, so Header1 doesn't always start a document and Header2 won't always follow.

A bit off topic, but the data sets are results from an experiment I'm mainting for a thesis.

I want to be able to capture type 1 data found only in the first section (under Header1) using a single regex function. After capturing it I was going to use replace and another function to convert the captured data to a different form.

Initially I was using the regex `type1\h*=\h*([[:graph:]]*)` but this only goes line by line, and I've got hundreds of documents - potentially tens of thousands of individal lines to catch.

I can use regex to convert my data well enough, but my problem lies in that I have no idea how capture type 1 data from Header1 exclusively. Any help, tips or pointers to start some experimenting would be really appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You need to show some effort into solving the problem yourself before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not providing enough information.

Comment: Really? I've looked through dozens of questions here and a few seem to be fine with that. Well I was trying lookbehind, but I don't know how to get it move down the list whilst capturing the data I'm looking for. Give me a second and I'll type what I was just trying.

Comment: See help pages http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Please stop adding comments and edit any additional information that you may have into your question. Stack Overflow is not a forum

Comment: You have written quite a long question that doesn't explain very much. It looks like you have a standard config file, but you don't say what you want to *do* with any entries that you find under the given heading

Comment: And enter auto-posting my comments has caught me off guard, as has the 5 minute edit limit.

The documents are lists of data obtained from an experiment conducted for a thesis. I excluded what I want to do with the captured data because because I know how to accomplish it: converting the captured data into a different form via the replace function.

The question is long because @AdrianHHH first comment prompted me to reword what I'd tried, how it didn't work and what specifically I wanted to know.

Comment: `perl` and `notepad++` have very different ways of tackling this problem. I wouldn't use a single regex approach at all in `perl`.

Comment: I definitely know that the examples I've seen in perl are different to what works in notepad++. But [apparently](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) regex in notepad++ uses PCRE (perl) syntax. Otherwise I have no idea what syntax notepad++ uses. I can more suitably tag this if I knew but I can't find any more information.

Comment: So you want to parse an INI file using Notepad++? Or Perl? Or...? My suggestion: you got off track a little in the middle third of your question with all the regex stuff. Describe the actual problem you want to solve, rather than the problem you're having with your solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll edit my post now.

Comment: If the headers/sections are out of order, fix the process that produces that file.

Comment: Definitely my first thought, and it might be possible at some point, but at the moment it isn't feasible. The testing process using a dedicated PC that's on loan from my lab's equipment department. Even if I had the ability to recode the programs used on the PC, I would be very hesitant to do it in case I messed something up.

Comment: So, using Perl, you want to keep only the lines from the `[Header1]` section where the key ends in `_type1`, and your input is hundreds of `.ini` files? Is that pretty close?

Comment: Pretty much yeah, I've tried a few more variations of lookahead/lookbehind but still nothing.

Comment: The answer is - stop latching onto regex. It's a great tool for a specific task, but it is _NOT_ a parser.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. After the reaction here I was wondering if I should  move to writing a script to catch the data.

Comment: I'll set this question as answered seen as I doubt anyone will reply or vote up for visibility. Seems the original people who voted down because my post weren't feeling in a forgiving mood, hahaha cheers.

Comment: @ScottLawrence Yes, you should absolutely look into writing a script to do this. The "one regex to rule them all" that you initially envisioned is not going to work, I'm afraid. On the plus side, there are lots of Perl modules available to parse INI files, so 90% of the work is already done!

Comment: I can imagine how I gave off that impression, I started using regex two days ago. So when talked about 'knowledge failures' and stuff like that all I meant was I have so little experience with it that it's easier to assume regex is capable of it than not. As to the last part, great, under a bit of a time constraint. Cheers for all the help.

Comment: Have a +1 for handling these comments with grace :)  The following 1-liner should get you most of the way there: `perl -lne '$on = ($1 eq "Header1") if /^\[(.*?)\]/; print $1 if $on && /^data_label_type1\s*=\s*(.*)/'`

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks :) that should give me a good start on the road to finally being productive

Answer (score 0):

Regex apparently not capable of providing a solution, will use alternatives such as a parser instead.